# Replace specific range of lines with a string each regardless of content

Tags: sed

For example from line 4 to 8 (both included) I want to replace anything in each line with a string, for example "44":

```
cat file |sed '4,8s/*/44/'
```

However I don't get the desired result, it just keeps the same lines as they are:

`file` contents:

```
13
14
15
16
17

19
20
21
22
23
24
25
```

Any help?

Comment: why did you use `*` (which is a fine glob, but globs are not regular expressions) instead of `.*` (which is a fine regular expression)

Comment: @thrig I have no idea I guesses was the common sense. That fixed it thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thrig for commenting the answer:

```
% cat file |sed '4,8s/.*/44/'
13
14
15
44
44
44
44
44
21
22
23
24
25
```